# Como adicionar um Label dentro de um TextBlock pelo code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Como faço pra adicionar esses `Labels` dentro do `TextBlock`, pelo `code behind`?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Label x:Name="NumeroPergunta" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Label x:Name="Pergunta" />
</TextBlock>
```

O que eu tenho até o momento:

```
var tbPergunta = new TextBlock {Text = pergunta.Pergunta};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui usando a propriedade `Inlines` do `Textblock`:

Primeiro criei as `Labels` dinamicamente:

```
var lblNumeroPergunta = new Label
{
    Content = contNumeroPerguntas.ToString(),
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
};
var lblPergunta = new Label { Content = pergunta.Pergunta };
```

Depois criei o `TextBlock`

```
var tbPergunta = new TextBlock();
```

E por fim, usando a propriedade [TextBlock.Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), consegui adicionar os `Labels`:

```
tbPergunta.Inlines.Add(lblNumeroPergunta);
tbPergunta.Inlines.Add(lblPergunta);
```